# Forcing a newline in HTML output from XSLT

Tags: html, xslt, saxon

I have a requirement to be able to output HTML with a forced newline from XSLT (Saxon 12), basically to separate paragraphs. Things I've tried that didn't work:

- Putting `<br />` inside the `xsl:text` element. Obvious, but not allowed.
- Adding `style="white-space: pre-line"` to the HTML element (`p` or `a` or `span`) and using `&#10;` to get a newline in the HTML. This works, but XSLT will also put newlines in text elements on its own accord which will then be rendered as change-of-line by the browser. This can potentially cause very short lines inside paragraphs for specific window sizes.
- Various Unicode line-end entities (which are rendered as in-line characters, at least in Firefox).

The "proper" solution is probably to wrap the paragraphs in extra `<p>` elements, but that is not what I call a "local" change. Especially not if the closest surrounding tag is `<span>` or even `<a>`, which would then have to be repeated in each `<p>`. The style sheet has on the order of 5000 `<xsl:text>` instructions, so I need something that can be automated.

I have been told that the newer versions of Saxon has a solution for this, some secret code that will be converted to `<br />` when output to HTML. But I haven't been able to find it documented.

So how do I do this?

Comment: Oh, and post-processing the HTML is not a solution, that would be too easy. The requirement is for a style sheet that outputs browser-ready HTML.

Comment: Newer versions of Saxon? If you use Saxon 12 you are using the latest major release.

Comment: It would help if you could post minimal but complete samples to demonstrate the problem. Why is it Saxon or XSLT specific if the target format is HTML? Or does "The style sheet has on the order of 5000 `<xsl:text>` instructions, so I need something that can be automated" somehow indicate you want to process XSLT with XSLT?

Comment: With XSLT, if you use `<xsl:output indent="no"/>`, or, with XSLT 3.0, the finer grained e.g. `<xsl:output suppress-indentation="p"/>`, then I don't see why XSLT would "put newlines in text on its own accord".

Comment: The commercial editions of Saxon (i.e. PE, EE, CS) also have a proprietary `saxon:line-length` serialization attribute extension https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters.html to decide at which length lines are broken for indentation/pretty printing.

Comment: Your question is not clear. It sounds like you want to replace line break characters in the input  text with `<br>` elements in the output. This can be done using `xsl:analyze-string`.

Comment: @Martin Honnen, yes, 12 is the newest, I should have said "recent" -- I'm porting from Saxon7 while trying to add features.

And yes, good guess, this is the last step of a database-XML-XSLT pipeline where the XML-to-XSLT step is also implemented in XSLT. The final style sheet is about 1MB (25000 lines when pretty-printed) which is why I'm not posting a complete example.

I'm going to test the `xsl:character-map` route that @y.arazim mentions below, it looks a bit cleaner than alternatives involving `sed` and unlimited line lengths (`indent="no"). If no luck, I'll edit in a minimal case.

Comment: The constraint is that the XSLT style sheet is the deliverable, and some other entity will be processing a few million XML files into HTML using that style sheet. Which is why it would be nice to output HTML containing a `<br />` from an `xsl:text` instruction.

Comment: I would also suggest you see if `xsl:analyze-string` cannot work for you. It is difficult to advise without seeing an example of the input and the output you want to get. We only need a minimal example, not 250k lines. Using `xsl:character-map` to produce markup is a hack that should be used only as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you know what the proper way to do this is, but you're looking for an "improper" way that will involve less change to your legacy code base. That makes it hard for us to advise, because we don't really know what the constraints are.

My general approach to this kind of problem is that trying to do it in an "improper" way is precisely what makes code decay into an unmaintainable mess over time (the fashionable phrase for this is "technical debt"). Every change to a code base should be made the way you would have done it if you had been starting from scratch: because that might appear to be more expensive, but is actually cheaper over time.

If you want to output a `<br/>` element, then output a `<br/>` element. The fact that you have to break a single `xsl:text` instruction into multiple instructions shouldn't be an obstacle.

I'm afraid I have no idea what "secret code that will be converted to `<br/>` when output to HTML" might be referring to.

Comment: Maybe they meant  `xsl:character-map`?

Comment: Maybe the guy I spoke to was thinking of that. He promised me a link to the docs, but it never materialized. I'm going to try it, it looks like it can do what I need.

Comment: And yes, the proper way would be to split up the `xls:text` instruction and add `<xsl:element name="br" />` instructions. There's only a few places in the code base that generate the `xsl:text` instructions, so it would be doable if the other hints I've received here don't work.

Answer (score 0):

`xsl:character-map` was just what I needed, thanks @y.arazim.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps even has an example of generating not-quite-XML for JSP which I could adapt.